# Perl regex which doesn't work

Tags: regex, perl

I want to write a regex of this sort: (this is what i have currently)
(`$line` is a string)

```
$lhs = "E";
unless ($line =~ /^*\s\Q$lhs*\s[->]*\s\Q$lhs/) {
...
}
```

In the regex, this is what i what to find:

At the beginning of the string, 0 or more spaces followed by `$lhs` followed by 0 or more spaces followed by the characters `-` or `>` (could be multiple times such as `---->>>`) followed by 0 or more spaces, followed by `$lhs`.

It obviously doesn't work, but how can i make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: `*` is a modifier, so `^*` makes no sense. "zero-or-more start-of-line". `\s` is a SINGLE space, not "0 or more". you want `/^\s*...`

Comment: oh ok.. so is this what i need to write? `/^\s*\Q$lhs\s*[->]\s*\Q$lhs/` It doesn't give me an error like the last one but it doesn't work either (according to my verbal description in the original post)

Comment: what's the point of the \Q? that turns off metacharacters from that point forwards...

Comment: I thought i had to use it for the variable `$lhs`? never mind, i found the answer. I just had to add `*` after `[->]`. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Indeed, the `\Q` must be closed with `\E`.

Comment: So you use `\Q` and `\E` when in between you have characters you wish to escape and not be interpreted as part of the regex? Is it like using '\' for a whole string of characters?

Comment: @Gambit2007 Yes, exactly. It basically inserts a backslash before every non-`\w` character.

Comment: Great, thanks! I'm just pretty new to perl.

Answer (score 0):

I've found my answer:

```
$line =~ /^\s*$lhs\s*[->]*\s*$lhs/
```

Many thanks to Marc B for the help!